# (q/kdb+) Generating an automated list

Tags: kdb

**Example 1)**
I have the code below

```
5#10+1*2
```

that generates

```
index   value
0       12
1       12
2       12
3       12
4       12
```

How can I replace the number "1" by the index?
then generating

```
5#10+index*2

index   value
0       10
1       12
2       14
3       16
4       18
```

**update Example 2)**
Now, if I have, let's say

```
mult:5;
t:select from ([]numC:1 3 6 4 1;[]s:50 16 53 6 33);
update lst:(numC#'s) from t
```

the last update will generate

```
 numC   s     lst
 1      50    50
 3      16    16 16 16
 6      53    53 53 53 53 53 53
 4      6     6 6 6 6
 1      33    33
```

How can I generate the "lst" column as per below?

```
 numC   s     lst
 1      50    50+0*mult
 3      16    16+0*mult 16+1*mult 16+2*mult
 6      53    53+0*mult 53+1*mult 53+2*mult 53+3*mult 53+4*mult 53+5*mult
 4      6     6+0*mult 6+1*mult 6+2*mult 6+3*mult
 1      33    33+0*mult
```

I tried something like

```
update lst:(numC#'s + (til numC)*mult) from t
```

but I am getting an error

```
ERROR: 'type
```

Thanks vm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove take `#` and use `til` to simplify to:

```
q)10+2*til 5
10 12 14 16 18
```

Using `til` will create a list of a list of 5 elements (0->4), so you will not need take 5 elements from the resulting list. Take will only be required if your list of indices is greater than 5.

**Update:**

For your second example the following should work:

```
q)update lst:{y+x*til z}'[mult;s;numC] from t
q)update lst:s+mult*til each numC from t
numC s  lst
-------------------------
1    50 ,50
3    16 16 21 26
6    53 53 58 63 68 73 78
4    6  6 11 16 21
1    33 ,33
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would you mind to take a look at the question again? I added another doubt.

Comment: Updated with a new example.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
    q)x:5
    q)x#10+(til x)*2
    10 12 14 16 18
```

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/arith-integer/#til

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways with which we can get achieve this:
1) `10+2*til 5`

2) `(2*til 5) + 10`

/ take operator: The dyadic take function creates lists. The left argument specifies the count and shape and the right argument provides the data.
It is useful for selecting from the front or end of a list.
https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/NumberSign

```
q)5#0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8      / take the first 5 items
0 1 2 3 4
q)-5#0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8     / take the last 5 elements
4 5 6 7 8
```

use `take` operator `#` only when it is required.
say we have 10 elements, of which we need five on output, then we can use:
5#10+2*til 10

/ The til function takes a non-negative integer argument X and returns the first X integers